# How many authors wrote the Old and New Testament?

Tags: authorship

I know how many people wrote the Bible, that is, around 40. But what percent of that is Old Testament and what percent is New?

**Note:** *I know I could spend half an hour looking through the lists to split them up but 1. Since this is not quickly answered anywhere, let's make it easier for people who want to know, and 2. Maybe someone here will know off the top of their head.*

Comment: I’m looking for them seperated by ot and nt

Comment: In the question linked to the last eight are NT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it’s like this: 32 Old Testament and 8 New Testament

**old testament**

```
1   Moses
    2   Joshua
    3   Samuel
    4   Ezra
    5   Jeremiah
    6   Nehemiah
    7   Mordecai
    8   Author of Job
    9   Sons of Korah
    10  Asaph
    11  Heman
    12  Ethan
    13  Hezekiah
    14  David
    15  Solomon
    16  Agur
    17  Lemuel
    18  Isaiah
    19  Ezekiel
    20  Daniel
    21  Hosea
    22  Joel
    23  Amos
    24  Obadiah
    25  Jonah
    26  Micah
    27  Nahum
    28  Habakkuk
    29  Zephaniah
    30  Haggai
    31  Zechariah
    32  Malachi
```

**New Testament**

```
1   Matthew
    2   John
    3   Mark
    4   Luke
    5   Paul
    6   James
    7   Peter
    8   Jude
```

Comment: No one knows who wrote Hebrews, but you could add "Author of Hebrews" as a placeholder. Also, it is unlikely that Job wrote the book bearing his name, so I would just put "Author of Job" as another placeholder. Job explicitly asked that his words be written down. If he was capable of doing so himself, would he have asked this?